# How to merge all arrays of an object array to get unique values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I've got some data like this:

```
const items = [
  { _id: '1', reference: ['abc'] },
  { _id: '2', reference: ['def'] },
  { _id: '3', reference: ['abc'] }
]
```

The length of `items` is always different.

Now I need to get all unique reference strings in a single array. So the result should be

```
['abc', 'def']
```

as `'abc'` is a duplicate.

I tried to use a `forEach()` loop:

```
const references = []
items.forEach(i => {
  references.concat(i.reference)
})

console.log(references)
```

But `references` just gets an empty array result. Also with that I did not take care of duplicates...

---

I would like to use an ES6 pattern. With that I know I could use something like this:

```
const array1 = ['abc']
const array2 = ['def']
const array3 = Array.from(new Set(array1.concat(array2)))
```

But how can I do this using a loop to get every reference array of each item object - even if I do not know how many objects are in the item array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna do a functional style (map-reduce), you can do it like this

```js
const items = [
  { _id: '1', reference: ['abc'] },
  { _id: '2', reference: ['def'] },
  { _id: '3', reference: ['abc'] }
]

// extract references and put them into a single array
const references = 
  items
    .map(x => x.reference)
    .reduce((prev, cur) => prev.concat(cur))
    
// put them in a set to dedupe
const set = new Set(references)

console.log(references)
console.log([...set])
```

If you want to do fewer passes over the data, and also avoid the need for `Set` you could do.

```js
const items = [
  { _id: '1', reference: ['abc'] },
  { _id: '2', reference: ['def'] },
  { _id: '3', reference: ['abc'] }
]

const result = Object.keys(items.reduce((obj, {reference}) => {
  for (const ref of reference) {
    obj[ref] = true
  }
  return obj;
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

You can also trade expressiveness for performance with a fully imperative approach below.

```js
const items = [
  { _id: '1', reference: ['abc'] },
  { _id: '2', reference: ['def'] },
  { _id: '3', reference: ['abc'] }
];

const occ = {};
const references = [];
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  const refs = items[i].reference;
  for (let j = 0; j < refs.length; ++j) {
    const ref = refs[j];
    if (occ[ref] == null) {
      references.push(ref);
      occ[ref] = true;
    }
  }
}

console.log(references)
```

Comment: If you're going to use `.reduce()`, you may as well do the deduping there and then your unique references are Object.keys(references). You can skip the `.map()` and `new Set()` portion entirely, saving you 2 iterations through your dataset

Comment: @mhodges true. I was just thinking of the most straightforward/expressive solution, and the op mentioned they wanted to use `Set` so I did it that way. I can edit in that answer as well.

Comment: Well, the OP said they would like to use an "ES6 Pattern", which I don't think is a real requirement. I think that is the OP's attempt at a solution thinking that ES6 is "clearly more efficient than ES5". However, 1 pass through the array with `.reduce()` is more time and algorithmically efficient than 3 passes through the array. Your `for` loop solution addresses the issue of the inefficiency, but it's unnecessarily verbose - not to mention, not using any "ES6 Patterns"

Comment: @mhodges yeah I know. I updated it with what you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Sets, you can use `Set.add`, and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const items = [
  { _id: '1', reference: ['abc'] },
  { _id: '2', reference: ['def'] },
  { _id: '3', reference: ['abc'] }
]

var references = new Set();
items.forEach(i => references.add(...i.reference))
console.log(Array.from(references))
```

Comment: You can simplify it even further with `Array.from(new Set(items.map(item => item.reference[0])));`

Comment: For this case, it seems so. But because `reference` is an array, I'm assuming that there might be multiple values in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to other solutions here, but creates a reusable function:

```js
const uniqRefs = 
  items => [...items.reduce((s, i) => s.add(...i.reference), new Set())]


const items = [{"_id": "1", "reference": ["abc"]}, {"_id": "2", "reference": ["def"]}, {"_id": "3", "reference": ["abc"]}]
console.log(uniqRefs(items))
```